# jQuery Tabs - how to remove focus from them after clicking on a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery tabs, but when I select some and then press up/down button, cursor keeps scrolling through tabs instead of scrolling down the page. Anybody got an idea how to fix it? I know I should somehow bind "activate" event to the Tabs and remove focus every time, but I am not sure how to do it.
Found also examples of activate binding, but none of them works.

My Tabs:

```
<div id="tabs"> <ul> <li>
<a href="#tabs-1" >General info</a></li> 
<li><a href="#tabs-2" >Sights</a></li> 
<li><a href="#tabs-3" >Treks and walks</a>
</li> </ul> 
<div id="tabs-1">
```

etc etc....

Thanks a lot, Jozef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna add focus or active class to only that tab you click on then I prefer you use 'jQuery' - $this , to make it happend and in that way active or focus will only apply to the tab you click on.

Example:

```
$('li a').click(function(){

   $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution looks good. However, for some reason it didnt work - I added also alert into function and it wasnt displayed too. So it seems that this code is not executed after I click on some Tab. Have you got an idea what could be blocking it?

Comment: Try using $(" li ") instead of $(' li a ')
Also you must have css setup before using jquery to add class on click.

Comment: Also, I prefer you should use jQuery UI for this and customize it as per your requirement. Check this link and view source code aswell - https://jqueryui.com/tabs/